# Several parts of UI are not painted

Tags: wpf

We have a very strange behaviour of a WPF application. Sometimes (not very ofen), some parts of the user interface are simply not painted.

Just recently the save button and a text box on the configuration view didn't show up. Even more strange is that after a relogin, what results in a new view instance, the problem is still present.
Sometimes it helps to hover the mouse over the position where the missing controls usually are to get them visible. But switching the tab page and then back to the original one with the missing controls they are all missing again. Other controls won't show up by hoovering the mouse over them.

Another problem is that dialogs are sometimes screwed up. Parts of the dialog are displaced vertically. But when e.g. a text box inside the dialog gets the focus, it is painted correctly while the rest of the dialog stays displaced.

I don't have the slightest clue what causes this problem. Any idea is welcome.

**[Edit 1]** So far we have seen this always on Windows XP. Windows 7 seems to be Ok. Also switching to Software-Rendering seems to fix the problem on Windows XP but I'm not sure on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by switching the RenderMode to SoftwareOnly. It seems to be a .NET 4 issue when running on Windows XP:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
    protected void SetSoftwareRendering()
    {
        System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual( this ) as System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource;
        System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget hwndTarget = hwndSource.CompositionTarget;

        hwndTarget.RenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
    }
}
```

Alternatively one can write

```
System.Windows.Media.RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

All windows are inherited from MyWindow and can decide wether or not they want the software rendering. Currently we don't use this flexibility and have it enabled on all instances.

Answer (score 1):

If this happens in other WPF applications too it might be your hardware, driver, OS or .NET software.

If not, the only option is to try and reproduce in a minimal case and on several machines.

Are you able to make a minimal version that has the problem en post the code?

Comment: As far as it happens only sporadically it is quite impossible to strip down the application to an minimal case.

Comment: Does it happen on other machines with the same OS as well?

Comment: Yes. We have seen it on several touch panels and also on a Laptop.

Comment: Are there any triggers/animations that are active and might conflict?

Comment: No, neither any triggers nor animations. It are simply data bound controls or in case of the displaced dialog a new window shown as modal dialog.

Comment: We are using Microsoft Prism.

Comment: I am sorry but if you cannot reproduce the error it is very hard for me/us to figure out what is going on. AFAIK Prism doesn't 'do' anything with the UI. So unless you are loading modules in constructors of UI classes or something like that, Prism isn't causing this.