# Parts of the window gets black

Tags: wpf

In my application, when I add items to a certain ListBox, parts of my windows gets black (not only the ListBox ). It happends only when the window is Maximized, and if I change its state to normal, it gets rendered. And also if I hover a control (while he is still black) it gets rendered (on;y that specific control).

Any idea?

Comment: Good luck getting help with that description.

Comment: Only a guess, but perhaps switching to software rendering helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5869291/128886

Comment: That was a good guess... Thank you.